# Javascript table refresh no jquery

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am doing javascript without jquery implementation.
Currently I am populating a table and want to refresh it when a new data in added without reloading the new page. As of now the refreshing works but it keep creating new table. How do I achieve refreshing on the table itself, without keep adding new table?

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmutzzsv/)**

**Code**

```
var schedule = [
{ date: "Monday, 9:00am", team1: "Chasing", team1Score: "13", team2: "Amsterdam Money Gang", team2Score: "9"},
{ date: "Monday, 9:00am", team1: "Boomsquad", team1Score: "15", team2: "Beast Amsterdam", team2Score: "11"},
];

function run(){    
var len = schedule.length;
var table = document.getElementById('table1');

for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var s = schedule[i];

    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.date;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team1;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team1Score;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team2;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team2Score;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}}

setInterval(function(){
    run() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 2000);
```

Comment: You want the new data/records from the server ?

Comment: If you don't want new rows why are you adding them in your function then?

Comment: as of now I have json passed from server,the var schedule is sample of my json

Comment: You can also do workaround like first clear the table before adding the new rows like `table.innerHTML="";`

Comment: @HankyPanky my mistake i mean when the refresh is refreshing, it create a new table under another table ,

Comment: now see your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wmutzzsv/1/

Comment: @KalpeshRajai that is a good solution, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @HankyPanky, I only add one line there and does not any extra stuff and I think that it I am not going to post an answer. Now I am going to add that answer, as said.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your answer is only 1 line long. It is a good answer and a possible solution to this problem and will be helpful for readers in future

Comment: @HankyPanky Oh Okay thanks. I am going to add this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `inspect` your page in development mode(by pressing F12) than you can see that there is `no new table` is adding, actually what are you doing is that you first get the `table` and after that you are starting to adding new rows to it but the table is also have the old rows. so that's why you are seeing the same rows multiple times. To overcome this problem first you have to clear the table.

You are also get the tables every time but there is no need to that, by doing that you are simple increase the load on the browser because `JavaScript` every time traverses to you each and every `DOM` to find your `ID`.

Simply made the below changes to overcome this problem.

```
var table = document.getElementById('table1');

var schedule = [
{ date: "Monday, 9:00am", team1: "Chasing", team1Score: "13", team2: "Amsterdam Money Gang", team2Score: "9"},
{ date: "Monday, 9:00am", team1: "Boomsquad", team1Score: "15", team2: "Beast Amsterdam", team2Score: "11"},
];

function run(){    
var len = schedule.length;
table.innerHTML="";

for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var s = schedule[i];

    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.date;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team1;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team1Score;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team2;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team2Score;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}}

setInterval(function(){
    run() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 2000);
```

Happy Coding...